# mysql query getting last id and insert value if not exist

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to find a solution need assistance in `MySQL` script:

Here is my solution design:

1. Insert values in `qa_post` (which is in database1) table from test1
   (database2)
2. Get `max(postid)` from `database1.qa_posts` (which we
   just inserted in step # 1) and then
3. Insert values in `qa_postmetas`
   (which is in database1) but half of the values will come from `database2.test1`

Here is my script so far:

```
INSERT INTO database1.qa_posts (type, categoryid, userid, created, title, content, tags)
(SELECT  'Q_QUEUED', '1', '3', NOW(), f.title, f.img, f.tagsv
FROM database2.test1 f)
LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO database1.qa_postmetas (postid, title, content) 
(select MAX(postid) , 'qa_q_extra', f.URL
from database1.qa_posts b
JOIN database2.test1 f on f.id = b.postid)
LIMIT 1 ;
```

What wrong:

- `MAX(postid)` is coming from  `database2.test1` instead of `database1.qa_posts`
- I want to add logic that don't insert in `database1.qa_posts` until I verify `f.URL` doesn't exist in `database2.test1`. If it does exist don't do any insert

Answer (score 0):

`MAX(postid)` --> `MAX(b.postid)`

Make a UNIQUE index on `test1.URL`; then the INSERT will fail.  Do `INSERT IGNORE` so that the failure will be silent.

Comment: I tried MAX(b.postid) its a same thing... it get max id from database2.test1

Comment: When you run the SELECT by itself (not as part of the INSERT), which do you get?

Comment: even if I run the select by itself i get max id from database2.test1